# IIS Mysql Request Entity Too Large

Tags: mysql, iis

I am running mysql under IIS server. I want to import mysql DB to xampp but getting below error.
Request Entity Too Large

I have already tried increasing max uploaded size in php.ini not fixed
In IIS Configuration Editor changed the uploadREadAheadSize to max not fixed

Please help.

Comment: copy it directly https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html

Comment: I could achieve it by using Workbench.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: So have your problem solved? If it has been sovled, please post the answer and marked it so that any other can get help if they have similar problem.